# If $a$ is not a power of $10$, when $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S(a^n)=\infty$? ($s(m)$ is the sum of the digits of $m$.)

Tags: limits, number-theory

If $a$ is not a power of $10$, when $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S(a^n)=\infty?$$ ($s(m)$ is the sum of the digits of $m$.)

(I don't have any ideas to prove this.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I think that the sum of digits of powers is not expected to behave monotonically enough for the limit to exist. I would say that it is probably more likely that $\limsup s(a^n) = \infty$, and that the above statement is actually not true.

Comment: Interesting question. You need to show us that you've tried *something*...

Comment: misread the problem, sorry...

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It seems extremely likely that $\limsup s(a^n) = \infty$ for any such $a$. But I would dare to guess that even $\lim s(a^n)=\infty$ for any such $a$. It's a very interesting question in its own right. I'll give it some thought, and perhaps post a question here.

Comment: By the way, the "right" hypothesis is probably not that $a$ isn't divisible by $10$, but rather that $a$ is not a power of $10$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a proof for the weaker claim that
$$\lim\sup s(a^n)=\infty,$$
if $a\geq2$ is an integer coprime to $10$.

---

Let $a\geq2$ be an integer that is coprime to $10$. For each integer $n\geq1$ define $l(n)$ to be the smallest integer such that $a^n<10^{l(n)}$. Then by Fermat's little theorem we have
$$a^{4\cdot10^{l(n)-1}}\equiv1\pmod{10^{l(n)}},$$
and hence also
$$a^n\equiv a^{n+4\cdot10^{l(n)-1}}\pmod{10^{l(n)}},$$
which means that
$$a^{n+4\cdot10^{l(n)-1}}=q\cdot10^{l(n)}+a^n,$$
for some integer $q$, and clearly $q$ is positive. It follows that
$$s(a^{n+4\cdot10^{l(n)-1}})>s(a^n).$$
So for the strictly increasing sequence $b_1,b_2,\ldots$ defined by $b_1=1$ and
$$b_{n+1}:=b_n+4\cdot10^{l(b_n)-1},$$
we have, for all $n\geq1$, the strict inequality
$$s(a^{b_{n+1}})>s(a^{b_n}).$$
This shows that
$$\lim\sup s(a^n)=\infty.$$